# Updated property not considered in render()

Tags: reactjs

I wrote the following React test component:

> ```
> import React from 'react';
>
> class NavBar extends React.Component {
>     constructor() {
>         super(...arguments);
>     }
>
>     render() {
>         let d = new Date().toLocaleString();
>         let user = this.props.user || null;
>
>         if (user) {
>             console.log(user);
>         }
>         return <div>
>             {user ? <div>Hello, {user.first_name}!</div> : <div>Hello, stranger.</div>}<br/>
>             Time: {d}
>         </div>
>     } 
> }
>
> export default NavBar;
> ```

What happens: the `render()` method updates always as expected when the component receives updated properties. I know it because the "Time" value changes in the UI. I also know that `this.props.user` has a valid value, because the console logs the user data.

The weird thing is that the display of the user does not change: The component always shows "Hello, stranger".

Any idea?

Comment: something else is going on, code works fine https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/38925/

Comment: You're right, I found an other exception which caused a malfunction. Thanks for your fiddle!